# How to prevent k-window-titlebar from absorbing click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

Is it possible to prevent k-window-wtitlebar part of the Window class from absorbing click events?

I am inserting a form into the title of a window and find that I cannot click on any select boxes within the form, though buttons remain clickable. Is there any way to get the titlebar to let through click events but still allow the window to be dragged?

Here's a short sample that shows the problem -- the select box in the titlebar will flash a moment but then does not open. I'm not familiar enough with how Kendo is setup to figure this out easily, been bashing myself on this for a bit now. I know something is absorbing the click event and I've narrowed it down (I think) to k-window-titlebar. Any one have any ideas?

```
<link href="assets/ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/ui/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="assets/app/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/app/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<style>
form {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
<div class="shell">
<br><br><br><br>
    <div id="window1" class="window">
        <div class="client">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myWindow = $("#window1");


            myWindow.kendoWindow({
                width: "400px",
                height: "200px",
                title: "Test window",
                iframe: true,
                visible: true,
                actions: [
                    "Maximize",
                    "Close"
                ]
            }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();


        var $win = $('#window1');
        console.log($win);
        var $parent = $win.parent('.k-window');
        console.log($parent);
        var $title = $parent.find('.k-window-title');
        console.log($title);
        $title.append($('<form><select><option>one</option><option>two</option></select><button>test</button></form>'));

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: If you thnk the problem is related to the click event sequence, you should try add a `e.preventDefault()` on the click event of your `select`

Comment: That has no effect